# Does reinstalling MAMP delete the existing database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, save, mamp

I am new to databases and MySQL. My friend told me to use MAMP to create a localhost for my small scale database and so I did just that.

I am having problems with the port connections with it. It was perfectly fine when I had Windows 7 but when I upgraded to Windows 10, there is an error which says `APACHE needs open port 80 which is already being used by another service or application. Please reconfigure APACHE to use free port`. I have tried changing the port number in Preferences but the same problem still. I have found that the programs that use port 80 are Chrome and GoogleDriveSync. I have already tried closing both of these apps but still the same problem.

I decided to reinstall MAMP but before I do, I want to know if that will affect the database that I already have? When I run MAMP, the database is opened in PHPmyAdmin. I'm sure if that is separate to MAMP. So if I reinstall MAMP and then try to open my database, will all my data still be there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that you will lose the data. Just back it up before you do it. Go into phpmyadmin, select the database, click on "Export", select the "custom" radio button, and save to a file. Then when you reinstall, create a new database with the same name, and import the data.

Comment: The problem is that I CANT GO TO PHPMYADMIN! I can't start the MAMP connection so how else would I backup?

Comment: I just copied my entire MAMP folder in the C drive and pasted on my desktop. If I reinstall MAMP, could I just replace the new folder with the one on my desktop?

Comment: Try setting your ports to the following: Apache 8888, 8890, Mysql: 8889, and then try opening http://localhost:8888/MAMP/index.php?page=phpmyadmin&language=English

Comment: by the way, when I click the "set MAMP ports to default", it puts the Nginx port to to 7888

Comment: Via the MAMP docs:

These ports are configurable. The default configuration for MAMP uses ports 8888, 7888 and 8889 . That way, the MAMP servers can run alongside other servers installed on your PC. Should ports 8888, 7888 and 8889 be in use by a different application, please change the values accordingly.

Comment: What do you mean by "change the values accordingly"? Also, when I changed the numbers to something random, it worked after I restarted. But I don't want to use some random ports because I don't want there to be any problems in the future with my database or my laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I just read the Documentation of MAMP. **It will delete everything**! This means even the databases.

> Databases which you have created in MySQL are located in default location (C:\MAMP\db\mysql) they need to be backuped before uninstalling if you want to preserve them (because **they will be overwritten on next installation**).
>
> *- source: https://documentation-3.mamp.info/en/documentation/mamp-windows/*

Answer (score 1):

Save the "db" folder to another location on your machine and copy it back in there. When you restart MAMP your tables will be there.

I had to rename the "mysql" folder to "mysql56"

Answer (score 0):

No, you will likely get an error `XXX_DB.TABLENAME DOESN't exist`.

See [https://appsolute.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/215198206-How-do-I-do-a-complete-uninstall-and-re-install-of-MAMP-PRO-](http://ZenDesk).

So, just copy the directory `/Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56` and then put the new `/Applications/MAMP/db` in an archive folder with the old database copied. Restart the server and mysql. And you're back in working order.

If anyone knows to move the root directory of the mysql folder LMK! THanks.

And if you move your website directory inside the Mamp folder (`APPLICATION FOR OSX`), you can back that up too. That's why I keep the directory separate and easy to find in `XAMPP/htdocs2` so that I can remember where to find it and then change the directory every time the server has a bug.

Comment: `you're database will be there 100%` thats a pretty big claim to make